# Why Jboss 7.2 is overwriting HTML form action path with the domain instead of relative path?

Tags: jboss, tapestry, jboss-eap-7

We are migrating our aplication server from Jboss EAP 6.4 to Jboss EAP 7.2 that is running an tapestry 5.4.1 application.

When the page is loaded from an iframe, the server adds the domain to the action of the form, and this is incorrect.

```
<iframe src="https://www.example.org:7071/Proyect/endpoint/">
   <form class="form-inline" data-validate="submit" action="http://www.example.org/Proyect/endpoint/clienteunico.formcu" method="post" id="formCU">

</iframe>
```

The correct response would be like this

```
<iframe src="https://www.example.org:7071/Proyect/endpoint/">
   <form class="form-inline" data-validate="submit" action="/Proyect/endpoint/clienteunico.formcu" method="post" id="formCU">

</iframe>
```

We want to use a relative path and we want to know how to configurate Jboss or Tapesty.

In Jboss EAP 6.4 doesn't present this problem

Answer (score 0):

It may be related with HTTPS configuration, if you notice `<iframe src` is `https`, but `<form action` is `http`.

Also from [`Form.java`](https://github.com/apache/tapestry-5/blob/5.4.1/tapestry-core/src/main/java/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Form.java#L318-L322):

```java
    void beginRender(MarkupWriter writer)
    {
        Link link = resources.createFormEventLink(EventConstants.ACTION, context);

        String actionURL = secure && secureEnabled ? link.toAbsoluteURI(true) : link.toURI();

        ...
```

Comment: And Know you the name of the configuration option? Y searched a lot but I can't find it.

Comment: I don't know how to configure SSL in Jboss, sorry. It can also be different if it's behind a load balancer...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I overrided the BaseURLSource like the documentation of Tapestry.

From [HTTPS tapestry docs](https://tapestry.apache.org/https.html)

```
public static void contributeServiceOverride(MappedConfiguration<Class,Object> configuration)
{
    BaseURLSource source = new BaseURLSource()
    {
        public String getBaseURL(boolean secure)
        {
            String protocol = secure ? "https" : "http";

            int port = secure ? 8443 : 8080;

            return String.format("%s://localhost:%d", protocol, port);
        }
    };

    configuration.add(BaseURLSource.class, source);
}
```